# In small Media Query Menu is Not Set in Center Its Work In Both Medium or Xtra Small

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis');
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Xtra Small */

body {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.618em;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #383231;
    color: #454545;
}

.main-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header-img {
    text-align: center;
}

.header-img img {
    width: 232px;
    height: 232px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.header-content {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

.header-content h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bolder;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 7vw;
    margin-top: 54px;
}



.header-content h3 {
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 2em;
}

.header,
.menu {
    padding: 48px 0;
}


a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.header-content ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 43px;
}

.header-content ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    background: #81b09b;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 36px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0.4px solid #383231;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fa {
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.35s;
}

.fa:hover {
    color: #383231;
    transition: all 0.50s;
}

.menu {
    text-align: center;
}

.menu a {
    color: #454545;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

nav a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

nav img {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
}

nav span {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

hr {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 17px;
}

.footer div {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.footer div:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.footer a {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.footer span {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #81b09b;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 36px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.35s;
}

.footer .create-by {
    width: 100%;
    background: none;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #454545;
    font-weight: 100;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

/*Small CSS*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
    .header-content h1 {
        font-size: 6vw;
    }

    .header-content h3 {
        font-size: 2.5vw;
    }
    .menu {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .footer div {
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .footer div:nth-child(1),
    .footer div:nth-child(2) {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
    .footer .create-by {
        text-align: left;
    }
}

/*Midium CSS*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 62em) {

    .main-container {
        max-width: 70em;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        margin: 2em auto;
        background: #fff;
    }



    .header-img {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .header-content {
        text-align: left;
        display: block;
    }

    .header-content h1 {
        font-size: 4vw;
    }

    .header-content h3 {
        font-size: 2vw;
        font-weight: 300;
    }



    .footer div {
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0 !important;
    }

    .footer a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }


    .footer .create-by {
        text-align: right;
    }


}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexboxgrid/6.3.1/flexboxgrid.min.css" type="text/css" >
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="main-container">
        <div class="container-fluid header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 header-img">
                    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cwot07/profile_gif.png" alt="profile-img">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 header-content">
                    <h1>Amit Sharma</h1>
                    <h3>Web Designer & Mobile Application Developer</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon icon-fa cebook">
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon icon-twitter">
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon icon-googlePlus">
                                <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon icon-youtube">
                                <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="menu">
                                    <img id="profile" src="https://image.ibb.co/cwot07/profile_gif.png" alt="profile-img">
                                    <span>Profile</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="menu">
                                    <img id="resume" class="resume" src="https://image.ibb.co/dwKNtS/resume_01.png" alt="img">
                                    <span>Resume</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="menu">
                                    <img id="port" class="portfolio" src="https://image.ibb.co/m5Ot07/port_01.png" alt="img">
                                    <span>Portfolio</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="menu">
                                    <img id="contact" class="contact" src="https://image.ibb.co/bFUu7n/contact_01.png" alt="img">
                                    <span>Contact</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <a class="contact-no">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>+919871344356
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <a class="mail">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></span>amitmeet28@yahoo.in
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <a class="address">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>Rz New T 19 uttam nagar
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <span class="create-by">Create by Amit Sharma</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In Small Media Query Menu bar is not set in center but its work in both medium or extra small media query i try all possible solution. but did not work.
In Small Media Query Menu bar is not set in center but its work in both medium or extra small media query i try all possible solution. but did not work.

Comment: `Created by Amit Sharma` probably better.

Answer (score 0):

just add this CSS end of your CSS

```
<code>@media only screen and(max-width:768px) {
         nav ul {
    width: 85%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    }
    nav ul li {
    padding:0;
    width:25%;
    }
    nav ul li img {
    width:70%
    }
    }</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
    .menu-bar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```